# Runtime Error: Cannot find module "leaflet.awesome-markers" Ionic 3

Tags: node.js, leaflet, font-awesome, ionic3

I'm adding Font Awesome markers to an Ionic 3 application using Leaflet that can successfully display Leaflet's built-in markers, but when I attempt to import the leaflet.awesome-markers module, `ionic serve` reports a runtime error saying it cannot find the module `leaflet.awesome-markers`.

One suggestion I've followed is to remove the `node_modules` directory and let npm re-install everything. This didn't change the results.

Output of `ionic info`:

```
cli packages: (/home/jett/git/mobiLoc/node_modules)

@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.6.2
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.4.1
@ionic/cli-utils                : 1.7.0
ionic (Ionic CLI)               : 3.7.0
```

global packages:

```
Cordova CLI : 7.0.1
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 1.3.7
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3 ios 4.4.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.2.1
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.0.2
Node              : v7.10.0
OS                : Linux 4.4
npm               : 4.2.0
```

From `package.json`:

```
"@types/leaflet": "^1.2.0",
"@types/leaflet.awesome-markers": "^2.0.4",
"leaflet": "^1.2.0",
"leaflet.awesome-markers": "^2.0.4",
"typescript": "2.3.4"
```

Relevant code:

```
import * as L from "leaflet";
import "leaflet.awesome-markers";

private issueIcon: L.AwesomeMarkers.Icon;

this.issueIcon = L.AwesomeMarkers.icon({
  icon: 'heart-broken',    /* Heart with a crack */
  markerColor: 'red',
  prefix: "fa"
});
```

I'm new to both 1) Type Script and 2) debugging imports of 3rd-party modules that rely on type definitions. However, this doesn't appear to be a problem with resolving types -- my IDE is able to recognize the types defined within the `leaflet.awesome-markers` file. No compile/transpile errors/warnings either.

Because there are no compile-time problems, this appears to rule out a permissions problem on that module, but I've checked that all node_modules are installed local to the project and have the same permissions throughout the directory.

Interested in other approaches to debugging this.

Comment: how did you import ? can you add the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't fully understand how `npm` or my IDE is resolving imports, but I did stumble across a command that provided far more detail regarding the attempt to resolve the import. To get the extra detail, I used

```
npm run build
```

instead of

```
ionic serve
```

The `npm run build` command provided details of the various paths and extensions it was trying to use when resolving this line:

```
import "leaflet.awesome-markers";
```

I found the build was able to resolve this file once I changed the `import` statement to the location of the actual .js file:

```
import "leaflet.awesome-markers/dist/leaflet.awesome-markers";
```